# Alignment in Delphi 10.2 for Android

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo

I understand how alignment works for Delphi for Windows, but with Android when I set the alignment of a control to Top, not only does the control's width become zero (or close to it), but I am not allowed to make the control wider.  I want to put two controls on the screen, one at the top, the other client, but I cannot figure out how to do this seemingly simple task.

Any hints?  Is there a tutorial?  This one from Embarcadero is wonderful, but nothing behaves on my computer the way it "should" or the way it does in the tutorial.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Layout_to_Adjust_Different_Form_Sizes_or_Orientations_(iOS_and_Android)

Answer (score 0):

I created a Panel and then moved all of the other visual components onto the Panel.  I then made the Panel aligned Client, and then was able to apply the other alignments to the other components easily.